# Serializing xml with variated fields

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I've got an XML file, that contains structure similar to this:

```
<MainData>
   <field>
   <otherField>
   <Strings>
      <string0>
         some nested nodes
      </string0>
      <string1>
   </Strings>
</MainData>
```

I need to deserialize this XML, but I'm struggling with `<Strings>` node. string [int]  contains always the same fields, so I could store Strings into `List<myString>` where myString is appropriate class, but I need to store the index string**0** too. Please, suggest, how to achieve this? I'm using C# and for all other serializations `using System.Xml.Serialization;`

Comment: Assuming that the number of `<string{n}>` elements is dynamic, `XmlSerializer` won't help you directly in this scenario - it does not expect a variable element name. Your best bet may be to try to parse it using LINQ-to-XML instead

Comment: I would first load the xml in a xpathdocument, modify the xml to match a good syntax 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about loading your XML in a XPathDocument, modifying the `string{n}` nodes by `string id='n'` and then serialize ?

Comment: As there are no more suggestions, I've done the task as you suggested.